# Can I use the Fullscreen API in JSFiddle?

Tags: jsfiddle, full-screen

I have the following JSFiddle, http://jsfiddle.net/brantolsen/ejUWt/. It does the simple task of changing from full screen to non-full screen each time the body is clicked using [the Fullscreen API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fullscreen_API). This works correctly when all content is copied into a local web page and is correct according to the [documentation found here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Using_full-screen_mode). However, on JSFiddle nothing happens.

Is is possible to make example code on JSFiddle go full screen?

Please note that I do not mean viewing the result as full screen, but getting the javascript full screen commands working.

Comment: Full screen does not work from JSFiddle.

Comment: [This was fixed a while ago](https://github.com/jsfiddle/jsfiddle-issues/issues/374). Trying the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/brantolsen/ejUWt/) today click the text in the body and it will go fullscreen.

Comment: @gman I'd recommend editing that into Brant's answer (I would suggest writing another answer, but I think their answer includes some additional information that might be helpful)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the reason after playing around with Chrome and inspect element. The result code is placed inside an iframe which disallows full screen commands.

I was able to temporarily work around this by adding `mozallowfullscreen` and `webkitallowfullscreen`, found at https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Element/iframe, to the iframe through the use of firebug and Chrome's debug tools.

However, it does not look like JSFiddle will allow you to customize the `iframe` that the code is wrap in at this time.

Answer (score 36):

You view the result in full screen like this -

> http://jsfiddle.net/brantolsen/ejUWt/embedded/result/

Just click the share button on top -

[image]

**Update:**
The "Share" button no longer is displayed at all. You can still get the full screen display by manually adding `embedded/result/` to the end of the URL of your Fiddle

Comment: Sorry, I was unclear with what I meant by full screen. I meant that I could not get the Javascript full screen api to work in jsfiddle not how to view the result as full screen. Thanks anyways.

Comment: Understood. JsFiddle uses iframes to show output. In fact, all those 4 boxes are iframes. So, there can be no regular way in which you can achieve this.

Comment: Note that this "Share" button does not appear until after you save the JSFiddle once, by clicking the "Save" button.

Comment: I think the "Share" button no longer is displayed at all. You can still get the full screen display by manually adding `embedded/result/` to the end of the URL of your Fiddle.

Comment: this quesiton is not about running jsfiddle without an iframe. It's about the [JavaScript/HTML Fullscreen API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fullscreen_API) not working in jsfiddle

Answer (score 8):

Use `http://fiddle.jshell.net/your-fiddle-id/show/light/` for example [this fiddle URL](http://fiddle.jshell.net/jdhenckel/auv3gc4f/8/show/light/).  This will open it without any frames.

Comment: Doesn't work for me: https://imgur.com/a/Y2VuRPZ

Comment: this quesiton is not about running jsfiddle without an iframe. It's about the [JavaScript/HTML Fullscreen API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fullscreen_API) not working in jsfiddle

Answer (score 2):

I think the other respondents to your thread looked at the iframe (crossdomain) issues and ignored the question.

Another awesome JSFiddle user, Jennifer Perrin, answered more than half your question in her post ["Get current page URL and title with jQuery"](http://jsfiddle.net/jenniferperrin/xX5XB/).

All that remains for you to do is to apply some logic on the URL returned and fashion it into a functional `http://jsfiddle.net/[userid]/[postid]/embedded/result/` link in an anchor that changes it's href to toggle fullscreen.

Comment: this quesiton is not about running jsfiddle without an iframe. It's about the [JavaScript/HTML Fullscreen API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fullscreen_API) not working in jsfiddle